# What is email etiquette while replying to questions from multiple people?

Tags: professionalism, email

Me along with a senior member (Mr. A) in my team received an email (on Outlook enterprise) from the project manager (Mr. B) asking for our availability.

Mr. A replied that he is availability & copied our line manger.

After few minutes, my line manager (Mr. C) nodded his approval & asked a a follow up question to us on a different but related matter via the same email chain.

Currently Mr.A B & C are all there looped in the last email.

Should I reply back individually the managers Mr B & C or would it make sense to reply as follows:

> Hi B,
>
> < bla bla >
>
> Hi C,
>
> < some other bla, bla >
>
> Regards,
>
> James

I may be overthinking this, but would like to know the email etiquette in this scenario.

*The reason I mentioned its outlook is because, the app seems to have send different emails, rather than grouping everything together into a single email like Gmail does.*

Comment: What do your other coworkers do in situations like these?

Comment: I actually joined this company a few days so I don't have any other co-workers to talk to. Since my role is remote based at the moment, that doesn't help either.

Comment: The way a mail thread looks in outlook vs gmail is just how they are displayed in the client and is configurable (they just have chosen different default views). There should be a checkbox in outlook "View->Show as conversation" that changes that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

List all their names at the top of the email.

Instead of breaking up the email by person, break it up by topic by using inline quotes and address the specific issues in the email itself.

For example

> Dear Mr A, Mr B, Mr C,
>
> Standard introduction
>
> ＞＞This is what A said
>
> This is an answer to the part above.
>
> ＞＞ This is something else A said.
>
> This is the answer to this part.
>
> ＞＞ This is something B said.
>
> This is the answer to this part here.
>
> Standard closing
>
> Regards,
>
> James

This way the whole email is inclusive of everyone, but cleanly defines what you are responding to.

Comment: In addition, structure the email so that the people you are directly addressing, those being A and B are in the To field of the email, and the people you are keeping in the loop are in the CC field.

Comment: This also makes sure everyone knows everybody else's questions have been answered and what the answer was. After all, if everyone was originally in the email thread that means everyone should be up to data.

Answer (score -2):

The thing to do is difficult to answer because we don't all the details of the questions, but you have three options:

- Send three single emails all addressed to each person
- Send an email to all of them like the one suggested by さりげない告白
- Send three emails, but cc any person who you might want to keep in the loop.

I would highly suggest against the first seeing as this seems like a conversation between you all.

I'd suggest option 2, if the questions feels highly related to the question by A and doesn't stand well on their own.
I'd suggest option 3, if the questions are only loosely related to the question by A.

Comment: Do not send 3 emails. If it's an email chain, that increases the chance of email chain splits, increasing the chances that important information is not effectively shared with all people. As a general rule, if the question was made visible to all people, the answer should be made visible to all people. Even if people don't care about the answer, they may care that it gets answered.

Comment: The exception is if you think the question should not have been asked in front of someone else. In that case, you should communicate privately with the asker. For instance, if you're in an email conversation with a client, and your boss asks how your children are doing, you should let your boss know ASAP that he may have not intended the client to see that. Then your boss can decide how he wishes to approach the scenario.

Comment: I definitely agree, which is why I only suggest doing it if it is loosely related and even then, cc the people who needs to be in the loop.

Comment: The problem I have is your line manager has made a decision to include those people in this discussion. Silently removing people from a conversation can mean that other information that is shared in the chain may not reach the right people. (Generally when removing people, you should clearly state so at the top of the email.) If you state that you are removing people it may look like you're second guessing your line manager.

Comment: I completely disagree, It was mentioned in that conversation, he didn't include people specifically for that question. As I said, if A is important as well, you can cc him. You don't need to keep anyone out of the conversation. If everyone is important, you can cc everyone.

Comment: It says that A, B and C were all looped in on the last email. You can't tell if this is deliberate or not, but given the question is on a related matter, and it's trivial to remove people from the email chain, I'm not sure why you'd make an assumption that your boss didn't want somebody to be privy to the response. Your assumption is that either your boss is lazy or incompetent, and I'm not sure you want to be in a position where you have to explain to your boss which you think they are.

Comment: Yes, but it never said the boss looped them in. It never said if they were looped in in regards to the boss's question or something else. This seems very much like a situation where too many conversations is going on in one chain.

As I said in my answer:
The thing to do is difficult to answer because we don't all the details of the questions.

Comment: "Currently Mr.A B & C are all there looped in the last email."

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't say WHY or by WHOM. The WHY is very important in this situation...

Comment: It also doesn't say why in the last email. The OP doesn't have access to any more information than what we have. He can see the boss has included everyone when he replied, unless the boss has gone out of his way to either say: "I have deliberately included everyone" or "I have accidentally included everyone", you really don't know.

Comment: We don't even know if the boss included everyone, stop making assumptions and use the info you are given.

Comment: You have to make assumptions all the time in communication. Don't be afraid of it. Putting aside Mr C for the moment (this fellow was never introduced) it's very clear to me that Mr B continued the chain (as it is explicitly stated) with Mr A on there. Wherever Mr C was added, someone has made a decide to expose him to the conversation and its contents. Unless there is a very good reason to second guess that decision, you should keep them in the loop.

Comment: Yes, I never suggested taking someone out of the loop though.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your answer, wouldn't that be your third option?

Comment: No, I said: "but cc any person who you might want to keep in the loop.". I earlier also said: "You don't need to keep anyone out of the conversation. If everyone is important, you can cc everyone".

So I most certainly never suggested taking someone out of the loop.

Comment: The first option would take people out of the loop which is specifically why I didn't suggest it at all.